# Session Value is Always null in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: session, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to store the values in session in asp.net core web api project. I have referred the below link to store the values in session.
https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-session-storage-in-asp-net-core/

But i am getting null always while getting session value.

Answer (score 1):

You need provide more details about your codes which doesn't work. But basically you can refer to below steps:

1. Add ASP.NET Core 2.0 web api application .
2. Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session NuGet package .
3. Modify your Startup.cs, call `AddDistributedMemoryCache` and `AddSessio`n methods in ConfigureServices function , and add `UseSession` method in Configure function :

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddMvc();

       services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
       services.AddSession();
   }
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
       if (env.IsDevelopment())
       {
           app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
       }
       app.UseSession();
       app.UseMvc();
   }
   ```
4. Get/Set session in controller(using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;) :

   ```
   [HttpGet("setSession/{name}")]
   public IActionResult setsession(string name)
   {
       HttpContext.Session.SetString("Name", name);
       return Ok("session data set");
   }
   [HttpGet("getSession")]
   public IActionResult getsessiondata()
   {
       var sessionData = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Name");
       return Ok(sessionData);
   }
   ```
5. Then you could make api call to `http://localhost:xxxxx/api/ControllerName/setSession/derek` to set session , and call to `http://localhost:xxxxx/api/ControllerName/getSession` to get session data .

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Whenever a new request comes in, all the values are null. It's like it can't figure out that these requests are coming from the same person. I have a .Net Core API running on port 5000 and a angular 5 app running on port 4200.

Comment: Same thing is happening with me... Did you get any solution on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Following tutorial will help to set up Session values in server-side in ASP .Net Core Web API application.

[Tutorial for Session in API Core](https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-session-storage-in-asp-net-core/)